# How can I get a ModelAndView in geoserver's OWS?

Tags: java, geoserver, modelandview

I'm Implementing a **geoserver's OWS**. I want to a `specific method of the OWS` get a `ModelAndView` as following:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    public class HelloWorld {

      public HelloWorld() {
        // Do nothing
      }

      public ModelAndView sayHello(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException, Exception {
        ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView("index");

        return m;
      }
}
```

**How can I do this**?